# Let $A_{2\times 2}$ with eigenvalues $2,-2$ and eigenvectors $[1,1]^T$ and $[1,2]^T$...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_{2\times 2}$ have eigenvalues $2$ and $-2$ and corresponding eigenvectors $[1,1]^T$ and $[1,2]^T$. Let $\mathbf{x_k}$ be a solution of the equation $\mathbf{x}_{k+1}=A \mathbf{x}_{k}$ with $\mathbf{x}_{0}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}3 & 3\end{array}\right]^T$. Determine the vector $\mathbf{x_2}$.

The solution is $\left[\begin{array}{lll}12 & 12\end{array}\right]^{T}$. But I don't see why. Please help.

Comment: Given the linearly independent eigenvectors and distinct eigenvalues, what matrix do you expect $(A+2I)(A-2I)$ to be? If you get that, you can zero in on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[3,3]^T = 3\cdot [1,1]^T$

And $A\cdot [1,1]^T = 2 \cdot [1,1]^T$

Then $x_{1} =A \cdot x_{0} =  A\cdot[3,3]^T = 3\cdot A\cdot [1,1]^T = 3\cdot 2 \cdot [1,1]^T = [6,6]^T$

Now, $x_{2} = A\cdot x_{1} = A\cdot [6,6]^T = A\cdot 6 \cdot [1,1]^T = 6 \cdot A \cdot [1,1]^T = 6 \cdot 2 \cdot [1,1]^T = 12 \cdot [1,1]^T = [12,12]^T$